# C - character concatenate to string

Tags: c, string, realloc

I have the following simple program that reads character by character a text file. Each time a character is read from the file, must go at the end of the **str** which is a string. For this reason I made a small function called **conc** which takes the character, reallocates the **str** and then takes the character at the end of the string (**str[count] = ch**).
After the EOF character, I put the **'\0'** character to the **str** as an end for the string variable.
My question is why the last printf displays garbage?? Any ideas??
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void conc(char* str,char ch,int* count);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
   char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   char ch;
   int count = 0,i;
   FILE* fp = fopen("path","r");

   if(fp == NULL){
       printf("No File Found");
       return 1;
   }

   ch=fgetc(fp);
   while(ch!=EOF){
       conc(str,ch,&count);
       ch=fgetc(fp);
   }

   str[count] = '\0';
   printf("%s",str);

   free(str);

   return(0);
}

void conc(char* str,char ch,int* count){
    str[*count] = ch;
    (*count)++;
    //printf("\n%c",str[(*count)-1]);
    str = (char*)realloc(str,(*count)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you realloc() the pointer. The changes you do to `str` will not modify the original pointer in `main()`. You are only assigning to the copy of the pointer `str` in `conc()`. You need to pass a pointer to pointer in order to modify it.

```
void conc(char** str,char ch,int* count){
    (*str)[*count] = ch;
    (*count)++;
    *str = realloc(*str,(*count)+1);
}
```

and pass a pointer to it from `main()`:

```
conc(&str,ch,&count);
```

Change the prototype to match:

```
void conc(char** str,char ch,int* count);
```

Others notes:

1) when `realloc()` fails it returns NULL and you will lose the original pointer. So you need to use a temporary and assign to the original. 
See: [Having dynamically allocated an array can I change its size?](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html)

2) [Casting `malloc()`/`realloc()` etc is also dangerous.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

3) Always check the return value of `malloc()` etc to see if the memory allocation failed.

3) Allocating one char at a time is not very efficient. Typical way is to allocate a buffer of size N and double the size when you `realloc()`.

Comment: Thank you Blue Moon. I appreciate your help and your time. Your extra notes really helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to pass `count` to your function because you are (or rather, should be) passing it a proper zero terminated string, and the new character should always be added to its end.

If you are going to modify `str` anyway, it's slightly better to start out with `str = NULL`. On its first call, set `str` to occupy 2 bytes to begin with, and add 1 character each next call.

Be careful with `char ch;` and then using `while(ch!=EOF) ..`! This will only work when your default `char` is signed. It will also prematurely stop when you encounter a byte `0FFh` in your input.

With these points in mind, I end up with this:

```
char *conc (char *str, char ch);

int main (void)
{
   char *str = NULL;
   int ch;

   FILE* fp = fopen("path","r");

   if(fp == NULL){
       printf("No File Found");
       return 1;
   }

   ch=fgetc(fp);
   while(ch!=EOF)
   {
       str = conc (str, ch);
       ch = fgetc(fp);
   }

   printf("%s",str);

   free(str);

   return 0;
}

char *conc (char *str, char ch)
{
    int last_pos;
    if (str)
    {
        last_pos = strlen(str);
        str = realloc (str, last_pos+1);
    } else
    {
        str = malloc(2);
        last_pos = 0;
    }
    str[last_pos] = ch;
    str[last_pos+1] = 0;
    return str;
}
```